# How to fix end index must not be negative in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-athena

Hi I try to create a table with a simple query as below:

```
select distinct 
    b.week_start_date,
    count(distinct visitor_id) as uu,
    count(distinct visit_id) as session,
    sum(1) FILTER (WHERE event_name = 'pageview') AS pageview
from  
    table a
join 
    table b on a.date = b.cy_date_num_yyyymmdd
where 
    a.date between '20211107' and '20211113' 
group by 
    1
```

However, I get an error

> GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: end index (-2147483642) must not be negative

And I need to manually clean the data from locations specified in the manifest. Athena will not delete data in your account.

So I tried to create a super blank table (query below) with defined format for each metric and then insert the above query into this super table. But it still returns the same error. Can someone help me fix this problem?

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.super_table 
(
    week_start_date date,
    uu bigint,
    session bigint,
    pageview bigint
)ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://abc-dataeng-temp-prod/xyz/product/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'parquet.compression'='GZIP');
```

Comment: I'd start with adding a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @jarlh i forgot to add here but it's included in my query.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` is redundant with `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @MatBailie I don't think that's the problem because even if I removed `DISTINCT`, it returns _GENERIC_INTERNAL_ERROR: Cannot allocate slice larger than 2147483639 bytes._

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the error (a large column value maybe?). Try this approach:

```sql
select
   b.week_start_date,
   count(distinct visitor_id) as uu,
   count(distinct session) as session,
   sum(1) as pageview
from table a
join table b on a.date = b.cy_date_num_yyyymmdd
where a.date between '20211107' and '20211113' 
and visitor_id is not null and session_id is not null and event_name = 'pageview'
group by 1
```